# Compare the Application settings of two Azure function apps

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-function-app

I want to compare the Application settings of two differents function app. I have one function app for the development and an other for the production and I want to check if I don't forget to add one setting on production.

I started with the Azure CLI and did :

```
az functionapp config appsettings list
```

which returns the list of the application settings.

Now how can I compare the names of the settings (not the value which will be different) of the two function apps ? It is possible to store them in a two differents `output table` and compare the `name` column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution using *PowerShell Core* where I first retrieve both appsettings (stage and prod). Then I iterate over the *stage* appsettings and check whether I find the same setting on the *prod* instance:

```
$stage = az functionapp config appsettings list -g my-rg-01 -n my-func-01-stage | ConvertFrom-Json
$prod = az functionapp config appsettings list -g my-rg-01 -n my-func-01-prod| ConvertFrom-Json

$stage | Foreach-object {
    if (-not $_.Value -eq ($prod | Where-Object Name -eq $_.Name).Value) {
        Write-Warning "Missing value or invalid value for key $($_.Name) found"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ! thanks a lot , I've adapted the code a little but it's ok .